# Why cookies, from AJAX response, does not appear in browser?

Tags: cookies, setcookie

Web application, hosted on localhost, makes AJAX request to another domain and it responds with a "set-cookie" header.

Here are the response headers in AJAX request to the Firebase serverless function.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: set-cookie
Set-Cookie:
auth=test; Max-Age=432000; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 03 Dec 2023 22:18:56 GMT; SameSite=Lax
```

After that, I expect to see "auth" cookie in chrome dev tools. But it does not appear in Application -> Cookies.
All other cookies there, cookies being set by localhost are visible, but not this one.
Tried to omit "Domain", "SameSite" attributes, but nothing works.

How can i set cookie with another domain response?